# Dialog Fragment and Detecting Touches to the Outside of Its Window

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-dialogfragment

I have a `DialogFragment` which contains a `ProgressBar`. What I want to do is to show an `AlertDialog` whenever user clicks outside the window of dialog fragment. In `onCreateView` of the dialog fragment, I can detect touch events inside the dialog fragment by calling `setOnTouchListener` to view that is about to be created. How can I detect touches to the outside?

By following a suggestion from another stackoverflow question, I tried to set flags:

```
    val dialogWindow = dialog.window
    dialogWindow?.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL)
    dialogWindow?.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH)
```

But couldn't detect touches in `setOnTouchListener`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class MyDialogFragment : DialogFragment() {                   

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)  
            : Dialog {                                        

        return object : Dialog(activity, theme){              

            override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent?)    
                    : Boolean {                               
                // Here you can handle the touch event        
                return super.onTouchEvent(event)              
            }                                                 
        }                                                     
    }                                                         
}
```

Also call the `setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)`, because touching outside the dialog will automatically dismiss it.